# Why 2's compliment is done for checksum calculation?

Tags: checksum

Why do we require 2's compliment to be done for the checksum, what would happen if we send it as it is or use 1's compliment.
I know it reduces the use of a subtraction module during verification, but does today's computers really require it?

Comment: _"the checksum"_. Which checksum?

Comment: eg checksum of Modbus and some other network protocols, i know modbus is kind of old.

Answer (score 0):

If by "we" you mean some spec, then it's because it is the spec, and probably made sense when it was written.  Changing that spec now for some dubious performance gain would break everything written against the old spec.